# Android Issue with Xamarin forms, mvvmcross, tabs and tasks

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

So i am using mvvmcross 6.2 and Xamarin Forms. I have  setup the tabs using this informaiton [Is there tabbed layout platform provided by mvvmcross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568720/is-there-tabbed-layout-platform-provided-by-mvvmcross). I have an iOS app that works fine, When running the android app i get the following exception whenever initating one of the tasks.

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'FragmentManager is already executing transactions'
```

The app is not busy while doing this so the busy indicator is not showing , however the app takes a very long time to change from login page to the tabs home. the exception does not seem to stop the process but it does really slow down the loading. 
in my homeviemodel
     public async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
        {

```
        tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<tab1ViewModel>());

        tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<tab2ViewModel>());
        tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<tab3ViewModel>());
        tasks.Add(NavigationService.Navigate<tabViewModel>());
        await CheckFortab5ViewModel();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

in my home xaml

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Root, WrapInNavigationPage = true, Animated = false)]
    public partial class HomePage : MvxTabbedPage<HomeViewModel>
    {
```

in my tabs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Tab, WrapInNavigationPage = false, NoHistory = true)]
    public partial class tab1page: MvxContentPage<tab1ViewModel>
    {
```

any ideas? should i even be worried about this?

Comment: Did you check the application output to see why the app is taking so long? Perhaps you could put breakpoints to debug it. One thing to note about tab pages on Android is that, unlike iOS, it also loads the contents of the next tabbed page, as a default behavior. There are ways of overriding this.

Comment: so it only seems to throw the exception if i wrap the root page in a navigation page.weird .. but that doesnt solve the issue though

Comment: It seems like you are following Xamarin Native instead of Xamarin Forms for the implementation of MVVMCross tabbed pages. You can check out the usage of `ShowTabsCommand` in this sample https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/345be5a69206d1827a8111801fdb284f5e007785/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.UI/Pages/RootPage.xaml

Comment: no , that command just navigates to the tabsrootviewmodel, which implements the way i have above.    ShowTabsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await NavigationService.Navigate<TabsRootViewModel>());